# Git does not show change even the file changed

Tags: git

Is git broken or what are we doing wrong ? ;-)

We found out, that a file was changed in a recent version of the git repository and I tried to figure out when that was using `whatchanged`.

How can this be:

```
$ git checkout 27773b72432e86d308d25d666663f237e50aa3fd Tools/foo.php
$ md5sum Tools/foo.php
85552061cae9832c11eb6607ac88e3d8 Tools/foo.php
$ git checkout master Tools/foo.php
$ md5sum Tools/foo.php
f38f51232785a432af2d1bd8db4429ed  Tools/foo.php
```

BUT:

```
$ git whatchanged 27773b72432e86d308d25d666663f237e50aa3fd..master  | grep foo.php
# empty result
```

How can this be?

Comment: You can configure git to ignore line endings for one thing. I don't think you can make md5sum ignore them :)

Comment: It's not line endings. It's a real code change. I just used md5sum to illustrate the problem

Comment: @Alex what happened when you apply a diff instead of whatchanged in final command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, you might want to try using

```
git whatchanged master..27773b72432e86d308d25d666663f237e50aa3fd
```

(It's true that you really should probably use `git log` instead, but that isn't related to why it isn't doing what you expect.)

Here's some info that will help understand why:

That notation `27773b72432e86d308d25d666663f237e50aa3fd..master` does *not*, as other users have suggested, mean "a range of commits starting at (but excluding) `27773b7` and ending at (and including) `master`".  It sometimes reduces to that, but that isn't what it *means*.  (And you'll see in a minute why the distinction is important.)

What it means is, "all commits that are reachable from `master`, but that are not reachable from `27773b7`".  (Where "reachable" means via parent pointers.)

Now if we assume that your commit graph looks like

```
 .... 27773b7 -- A -- B -- C <--(master)
```

then this would reduce to the type of "range" others have identified.  But in that case, you wouldn't be experiencing the problem.  That's because you've shown that the file at `27773b7` is different from the file at `C` (`master`), which means either `A` or `B` or `C` must have changed it.  If your commit graph looked like that.

So we can conclude that your commit graph *doesn't* look like that.

Another way it could look is

```
--- o -- A -- 27773b7 -- x ...
     \
      B -- C <--(master)
```

In this graph, `27773b7...master` means just `B` and `C`, because `A` is not reachable by `master`, and while `o` *is* reachable by `master`, it's also reachable by `27773b7`.

Now it's possible that the reason the file is different at `27773b7` is that it was changed either by `A` or by `27773b7` itself.  In either case, using `27773b7^` (as other answer suggests) would not help.

Which brings me back to my point:  if you really want to think of the `A..B` notation as defining a range, the start of the range can *not* be assumed to be `A`; if anything, you'd expect it to be the merge base between `A` and `B` (if there is one; sometimes it could just be the root of `B`s commit hierarchy) - and that's equal to `A` only if `A` is reachable from `B`.  And at any rate, you can't assume its a linear range of commits.

But understanding the subset of the commit graph it really indicates makes it more clear, that if `A..B` shows nothing you might need to try `B..A`.

Answer (score 1):

A range specified as `A..B` means from A to B but *excluding* A. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation

If revision `27773b7` is the only revision in which the file `Tools/foo.php` has been changed, then the range `27773b7..master` excludes exactly that only change.

**Update:**

What you want is to include A but exclude all its parents. The shortcut for that is `A^!`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations.

So, your command would be

```
$ git whatchanged 27773b7^! master | grep foo.php
```

One last note: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged suggests to use `git log` instead of `git whatchanged`.

To get a list of the file names only, you would say:

```
$ git log --name-only --format="" (other arguments here)
```

That would make sure that when you `grep` that output you would not accidentally match a comment.

Comment: You might also add a suggestion about how to get the desired results.

Comment: No, this analysis is wrong.  If the file at 27773b7 differs from the file at master, the issue isn't that the range is excluding a change that 27773b7 made.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger `git log` (or `git whatchanged`) prints what has been changed in each revision in the range. It does _not_ make a diff. So, when none of the selected revisions includes a change of the selected file, you won't see it.

Comment: @AdrianW - Yes, but that's beside the point.  If, as you assume in your answer, 27773b7 were an ancestor of `master`, AND the file differs between 27773b7 and `master`, that would mean that some commit AFTER 27773b7 had changed the file.  A change made by 27773b7 - the change that you keep pointing out would be excluded - would already be accounted for in the version of the file AT 27773b7, so it would not be a difference between that and the master version.  This is not hard to test if you remain confused (it took me about 5 minutes to set up and verify).